# How to get the index of a tab in AuiNotebook after a right click on a non-active tab?

Tags: wxpython

I create a menu that popups after a right on a tab. The menu contains three options: close, close other and close all. Right clicking on a tabs does not display its content (it not already displayed), it just show the menu that control the clicked tab. The issue is that right clicking on another tab popups the menu but the program does not know which tab was clicked.
Is there any built-in methods to get the index of a tabs in AuiNotebook after a right click event?

Comment: Have you tried `GetPageCount()` and `GetPageInfo(index)`

Comment: I want to get the index of a tab  if the mouse is over it, even if I don't click on that tab.

Comment: Then you need to `bind` to `wx.EVT_MOTION` and you need to put that in your question which asks about right click not mouse over

Answer (score 0):

Use `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN` to catch the event. The `event.page` will give you the clicked page.